# Azure DevOpsのPipelineの自動ビルトでdllを出力したい

Tags: c++, visual-studio, azure

Visual Studioで「構成プロパティ」→「全般」の「構成の種類」で「ダイナミックライブラリ(dll)」が指定されているときの出力である、.dll/.lib をAzure DevOpsのPipelineで実現するにはymlファイルをどう編集すればよいでしょうか?

対象となるコードはC++で、dllにエクスポートしたいクラスには`__declspec(dllexport)`が指定されています

参考に現在exeを出力するPipelineのymlファイルのビルドに関わる部分を添付します

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2015-win2012r2'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:  
- task: VSBuild@1
          inputs:
            vsVersion: '14.0'
            solution: '$(solution)'
            platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dllやlibの出力設定はvcxprojファイルで設定したパラメータに依存します。そのままでRelease/x64 フォルダーにビルドされたファイル(dll/lib)が出ているはずです。

あとはRelease/x64フォルダーにあるdll/libをcopyfilesタスクで$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)へコピーしてPublishArtifactsタスクで発行すればAzure DevOps内で保持されます。

挙動がわかりづらければSystem.Debugをtrueに設定すれば、コンソールにログが出ますので、どこに出力されるのかわかりやすいです。手動ビルド時にも指定できます。